# Using crystal in LTspice (where to get values for RCL)?

Tags: capacitor, oscillator, crystal, spice, ltspice

I'd like to simulate a schematic in LTspice driven by a crystal. An capacitor representing the crytal (as a resonant circuit) however it needs some specific values. Is there a table of common values for crystals? I took a look in some datasheets but I think no sheet provides the values I need, here for example: http://www.jauch.de/ablage/med_00000876_1355237027_SS2-021112.pdf

Kind regards

Comment: Some manufacturers have RLC models for their crystals. But regarding simulating a crystal oscillator, this is not for the faint-hearted ! The problem with a crystal (model) is that it has a very high Q which means that it will take an extremely long time in the simulator to achieve maximum amplitide. You can also "kick start" it in the correct amplitude and then it will stay there for a long time. This link might help: http://www.intusoft.com/nlpdf/nl16.pdf

Comment: What is your motivation for needing to have a crystal oscillator? As FakeMoustache said, crystals can be troublesome to simulate, and in most circumstances it is better to just put in a behavioural voltage source or even an RC oscillator.

Comment: Many thanks to you...My motivation is testing some oscillator circuits. The arising problems due simulation are known to me. However I am wondering about how to get the model values. I think this is necessary for engineering projects. I think I will use the common capacity of 15fF and calculate the missing values. I haven't found one datasheet with values for RLC ://

Comment: The spice simulation of an xtal is basically a capacitor on steroids, or really a kind of rlc circuit only. It is pretty far away from the physical model of a real crystal, although it behaves kind of similar. Thus it would make not much sense to come up with spice RLC values for a physical xtal in a datasheet. Thus the thing that makes most sense is to take a model that works ok for your purposes and then tweak it so that it fits the frequency you are looking for.

Comment: A *rule-of-thumb* for fundamental mode AT-cut crystals involves the ratio of parallel to serial capacitance of about 300. For example, your 15fF series capacitance would be associated with 4.5pF parallel capacitance. Is your crystal an AT-type?

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent circuit isn't only a capacitor it is series resonator with L, C and R and parallel a static capacitor C0.

In the link you will find the measured value for a 8MHz crystel.
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/43/8MHz_Crystal_VNWA.png